# Killing ssh session kills running process

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I'm connecting to my ubuntu server using ssh. I start an encoding program using a command. However, it seems that when my ssh session closes (because I started it on a laptop which went to sleep). Is there a way to avoid this (of course preventing my laptop from sleeping is not a permanent solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screen is the best for you.

```
screen -S some_name
```

than run it. Detach it with: ctrl+a d

Next time, attach it with:

```
screen -rd some_name
```

You can have more runnning screens. To show the list of them:

```
screen -ls
```

Answer (score 5):

Run your command with [`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) or use [`screen`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen)
`nohup` is better when your program generate some loging output because it's forward to file and then you can check it, but with screen you can detach ssh session and when you log again you can restore your work-space. For encoding I'll use `nohup`. It is easier and you probably run it in background, so you really don't need detaching

Answer (score 1):

Install "screen" on your ubuntu server, that way you can start any program in your session, disconnect the output of the program from your current session and exit.

Later when you connect again to your server, you can restore the program which will continue running and see its progress.