# How to run my deep learning model on server without interrupting even after disconnecting my system from the server?

Tags: ubuntu, machine-learning, server, deep-learning

All my data is on the server. How to run the model on server even after disconnecting the system. As i have huge data it takes min of 10 hrs to train the model.

Comment: If i understand, you run a local script using the data on the server. Maybe you can try to execute a server-side script to train your model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Killing ssh session kills running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546651/killing-ssh-session-kills-running-process)

Comment: I'm sure there's other duplicates too...

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-run-a-command-which-will-survive-terminal-close https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222307/preventing-terminal-disconnection-from-killing-a-running-job-in-zsh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/in-linux-how-to-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-s

Answer (score 2):

If you can run your script on the server, it is enough to run it with nohup and add an '&' at the end. 
For ex: `nohup python file.py &`. 
This will run the process in the background and also it won't be attached to your current ssh session. 
 To ensure it's running, you can do a `ps -aux` command and search for it. 
Also all logs will go to a file nohup.out.